# How convert current date to a DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: python

How can I get the the import function to convert the date into a European date ?  Example: (‘4/7/14’) returns ‘07/04/12’

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)
```

Comment: `today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

that is what [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) is for. have a look at the [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) to get your desired result.

for example:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

print(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))     # 2020-12-02
print(today.strftime("%a %d %b %Y"))  # Wed 02 Dec 2020
print(today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))     # 02/12/2020
```

Comment: How could I use the return function to do it instead of the print function?

Comment: `return` is something you can only use inside a function. `strftime` returns a string; you could always assign it to a name: `today_str = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`. or what do you mean?

Comment: Once I complete the function, I would want it to return the converted date by passing a parameter. Like for instance def european(date):  then at the end like   return European_date which would give me a converted value

Comment: `def european(date): return today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: Any suggestions for building the function so it runs smoothly? I’m a bit confused

Comment: i have no idea what you really want, sorry. maybe you should describe that precisely in a fresh question and post the attempts you made to solve your problem.(how does the suggested function not run 'smoothly'?)